# Javascript regexp - only if first character is not an asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex, negate

I am using a javascript validator which will let me build custom validation based on regexp

From their website: `regexp=^[A-Za-z]{1,20}$` allow up to 20 alphabetic characters.

This will return an error if the entered data in the input field is outside this scope.

What I need is the string that will trigger an error for the inputfield if the value has an asterix as the first character.

I can make it trigger the opposite (an error if the first character is NOT an asterix) with:

```
regexp=[\u002A]
```

Heeeeelp please :-D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about:

```
^[^\*]
```

Which matches any input that does *not* start with an asterisk; judging from the example regex, any input which does not match the regex will be cause a validation error, so with the double negative you should get the behaviour you want :-)

Explanation of my regex:

- The first `^` means "at the start of the string"
- The `[` ... `]` construct is a character class, which matches a single character among the ones enclosed within the brackets
- The `^` in the beginning  of the character class means "negate the character class", i.e. match any character that's *not* one of the ones listed
- The `\*` means a literal `*`; `*` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so I've escaped it with a backslash. As Rob has pointed out in the comments, it's not strictly necessary to escape (most) special characters within a character class

Comment: you don't need to escape the * inside []

Comment: @Rob: You're probably right. I've found that it depends on the platform, but I've never had any problems explicitly escaping using a backslash

Comment: fair enough, I was only being pedantic because you got your answer in first :P

Comment: @Rob: [FGIW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) syndrome, sorry ;-) In any case, it's good for others to know that escaping inside a character class is usually unnecessary

Comment: Actually this will trigger an validation error if there is an asterix anywhere in the input value, not only if the first character is an asterix...

Comment: @Splynx: Are you sure you included the first `^` (which anchors the rest of the regex to the beginning of the string)? The regex should only ever match a non-empty input with the *first* character not being a `*`

Comment: My bad, it did in fact only check on the first character it seems - any ways it validates just like it should - thank you again!

Comment: @Splynx: No problem ;-) By the way, if you need it to pass an empty input as valid too, you can use: `^(?:[^\*]|$)`

Answer (score 3):

How about `^[^\*].+`.

Broken down:

- `^` = start of string.
- `[^\*]` = any one character not the '*'.
- `.+` = any other character at least once.

Comment: This is better answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert character class by using ^ after [

`regexp=[^\u002A]`