# How can I filter by the first letter?

Tags: jquery, filter, filtering, jquery-isotope

I am trying to setup a filter in isotope that will filter by only the first letter of text in an  tag. Any help is appreciated! (new to javascript!)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use regular expressions?

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '^[^\*]' });
```

•The first ^ means "at the start of the string"
The [ ... ] construct is a character class, which matches a single character among the ones enclosed within the brackets

•The ^ in the beginning of the character class means "negate the character class", i.e. match any character that's not one of the ones listed

•The * means a literal *; * has a special meaning in regular expressions, so I've escaped it with a backslash.

Src= [Javascript regexp - only if first character is not an asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293859/javascript-regexp-only-if-first-character-is-not-an-asterix)

Comment: I believe I can use expressions, yes. So, if I wanted to turn that into a click function, i.e. when a link for "A" (<a href="#A">A</a>) is clicked it will filter all titles within <h2> tag that begin with "A", how would I write out that out?

Comment: It will be something like this, but will probably need tweaking.

`$('#IDofyourbutton a').click(function(){
    $('#container').isotope({ filter: '^[^\A]' });
});`